# exclusions with '-' when using string versions (underscore suffix such as gather_()) of dplyr/tidyr functions

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyr

Normally with dplyr/tidyr, I can achieve exclusions with negation

```
... %>% gather(x, -y)
```

However, currently, I want some variables to be specified programmatically *and* be an exclusion, so ideally

... %>% gather_(xVar, -yVar)

where xVar and yVar are character variables (say, with values 'x' and 'y').

Are exclusions simply disallowed with the string versions of functions, or is there a way to do them?

Both of the obvious culprits `-yVar` and `paste0('-', yVar)` seem to produce errors.

Comment: I think this is a good use for `matches`, see the examples at the bottom of `?select`. I'm surprised you are using `gather()` as your example, it's in `tidyr`, not `dplyr`.

Comment: amended to tidyr/dplyr

Comment: Perhaps you could also edit it to a valid `gather` call, with example data? After `data`, the next two `gather` arguments are `key` and `value`... I don't think "not column y" is a good argument for `value`. (Or use a different function, I'm having trouble thinking of a use case for a negative column in `gather()`... an example with built-in data would make it clear).

Comment: I'm not a dplyr/tidyr user but I would remind you that the numeric-negation operator is not effective with character vectors when used with the two argument version of "[". You would need to use the logical negation operator `!` with that function. You do not offer a test case which may explain the lack of attention to this question so far. Perhaps if you edit it to have a complete example it might get more attention.

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem recently. I used the workaround of calculating the included columns myself. This is not entirely satisfactory, but I don't think that this is currently possible with `gather_`. The issue seems to be in the `select_vars_` function. You can circumvent it using the `exclude` option in `select_vars_`.

```
# creating sample data from example in gather
stocks <- data.frame(
  time = as.Date('2009-01-01') + 0:9,
  X = rnorm(10, 0, 1),
  Y = rnorm(10, 0, 2),
  Z = rnorm(10, 0, 4)
)
# original call using gather
gather(stocks, stock, price, -time)
# calculating select_vars yourself
stocks %>% gather_("stock", 
                   "price", 
                   names(.)[!"time" == names(.)])
# using exclude in select_vars_
stocks %>% gather_("stock", 
                   "price", 
                   select_vars_(names(.), 
                                names(.), 
                                exclude = "time"))
```